# Are there any XML/XSL editors that can show transformations in real time?

Tags: css, xml, editor, xslt

I'm converting all of our Crystal Reports to use a home-built reporting system. Essentially, I serialize report objects to XML, transform that with XSL to HTML/CSS. Everything works beautifully, except for the design process.

Once I get the XML built correctly, I have to open up the XSL and CSS in SciTE, edit, reload in IE, lather, rinse, repeat. I'd love it if there was an XML/XSL editor that could show the transformation in real time and speed up my process. Can anyone make any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Altova XmlSpy for creating/editing xml/ xslts, getting xslt outputs, making calls to web service, evaluating xqueries in the database and many more things. It is a very powerful all-purpose xml tool. Requires a license though.

Comment: Do you know any way to change the output directory? All of the CSS/images are in a nested folder structure off of the user's temp directory, and are referenced with relative paths. The output goes to the temp directory, screwing up the paths, so none of the CSS or images are applied.

Comment: Why don't you include the CSS path in the xslt temporarily just to see the proper output

Answer (score 3):

This one is online javascript editor.

http://www.purplegene.com/static/transform.html

No matter you are a Windows, Linux or Mac user it will simply work!

Answer (score 2):

The `<oXygen/>` XSL / XSLT Editor can do XHTML previews.  See the "Preview Transformation Results" section of http://www.oxygenxml.com/xslt_editor.html.

Comment: I can't seem to find the "Preview Transformation Results" in the actual program. Any idea where I should look? Hunting through every menu has yielded nothing yet.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio supports XSLT processing as does [XML Notepad](http://www.codeplex.com/xmlnotepad).

XML Notepad is free.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the XSLT debugger in Visual Studio. Very useful.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255605.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Syntext Serna presents a real-time WYSIWYG view of XML based on XSLFO.